# ASP.NET prepending ContentPlaceHolderID_ to DIV tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying ot use `C# / ASP.NET` to pull a date from an `Oracle Database` and if the date is later than a certain day, hide a section of a form. The problem is, normally when I have been using a div `runat=server` to call from within `ASP.NET` I can just say `CONTROLID.Visible=true` and it works.

For some reason this form when run is prepending "mainContent_", the `ContentPlaceHolderID` of the form plus an underscore, to any DIV's run at the server. This means my CONTROLID is then renamed to `mainContent_CONTROLID` and is not shown.

How do you prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `PlaceHolder` is an [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx). ASP.NET, by default, builds a unique client ID based on the naming container hierarchy.

Use `control.ClientID` in your client script or change the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to `Static`.

Comment: Awesome.  Been doing this a year and this is the first time I have run up against this.

Comment: When you say, control.ClientID, how would you do that on a DIV? Say <div id="foo" runat="server"></div>  I understand the part of changing it to <div id="foo" ClientIDMode=static runat=server> but how would you reference that as a control?

Comment: E.g., to access with javascript: `var elem = document.getElementById("<%= foo.ClientID %>");`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="yourControlId" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**From MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Set `ClientIDMode="Static"` for div.

[image]